# How to make apps script to send email with the information matching with survey

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I am trying to do is,
If someone completed the survey, then according to his survey, send several values from the datasets. But I could not make this condition in JS version..

Like in picture 1, send email to the first person

1. How many pets are matching with his preference,

   count if where status = Adoptable.

   Preferred Pet species = Dog

   Age  = Adult or kitten

   Gender  = Male

   Size = Small
2. The information of adoptable pet
   Name, Primary Color, Characteristics from the 1.

[The google form survey result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47U4a.png)

[The data of pet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB37C.png)

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()


  // get sheets
  var response_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('survey_sheet');
  var score_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('pet_data');

  var Avals = response_sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

  // get email address
  var emailAddress = response_sheet.getRange(Alast,2).getValue();
  
  // count value of matching data
  var count_pet = ()

  // create message
  var subject = "Adoptable Pet List"
  // greetings
  var message = "Hello, This is the adoptable pet list for you.\n\n There are count_pet are 
  available matching with your preference \n There are [Name], [Primary Color], 
  [Characteristics ]"
  var text = sheet.getRange(idx,2).getValue();
    
  message = message + text + '\n'
  // Send Email
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add the data as text, not as image, also whow what you have tried to build the condition or make a more specific question and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This answer provides a summary of the matches currently available in tabular format.

GS:

```
function onFormSubmitForSpreadsheet(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('pet data')
  const vs = dsh.getRange(2, 1, dsh.getLastRow() - 1, dsh.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter(r => r[3] == e.values[2] && r[7] == e.values[3] && r[8] == e.values[4] && r[9] == e.values[5]).filter(e => e);
  if (vs && vs.length > 0) {
    const emailAddress = e.values[1];
    const subject = "Adoptable Pet List";
    let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah1');
    t.tabledata = vs;
    t.lr = vs.length;
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", { htmlBody: t.evaluate().getContent() });
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <p>Your can write an introduction here</p>
  <p>The following table is a summary of the current <?= lr ?> matches
  <div id="tabledata">
       <? var vs = getMyData(); ?>
       <table>
         <? vs.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
           <tr>
           <? r.forEach((c,j)=>{ ?>
             <? if(i == 0) { ?>
            <th style="padding:2px 5px;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;"><?= c ?> </th>           
           <? } else { ?>
             <td style="padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid black;"><?= vs[i][j] ?> </td>
           <? } ?>
         <?  }); ?>
           </tr>
         <? }); ?>
       </table>
     </div>
     <p>Your can write an ending here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I you wish to provide your data I can test it and fix any minor issues.

Comment: If you have any problems please provide an exact error and line number relative to the begin of the function so we can find and correct the issue quickly.

Comment: The function is intended to be an onFormSubmit triggered function so it cannot be run without supply the event as the trigger would provided.  Sorry you can't run it from a menu or the script editor